# React how to change focus of inner component's input box from the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that renders several list elements from an array. This child component's list items when clicked turns to input boxes, and can be changed. But I need to also put focus on the input box when it's rendered.

Here is a quick view of what my app is so far.

- I'm making list items from an array in the state and it's then mapping around while populating the array items in the parent components render function (like any other tutorial shows).

  ```
  render: function() {
  var listItems = this.state.ingredients.map(function(item) {
      return <ListItem key={item.id} id={item.id} refer={item.ref} handleChange={this.toggleEnv} env={item.env} ingredient={item.text} />;
  }.bind(this));
  ```
- **id** for callback from the child component to search the array using id.
- **env** for toggling states from list item to input box and back to list item.
- **toggleEvn** is the function i use for every manipulation of the child component with callback a child component make.
- Now that refer property where I pass the item.ref to the child component so it can attach it to the input and then use

`componentDidMount: function() {
        ReactDom.findDOMNode(ref-name-passed-from-child-component-callback).focus();
}`

Where in the child element i pass clicked list items ref (which is equal to input box's ref) to the callback so it can be captured by the parent but it passes **null** so i can't add the focus from `ReactDom.findDOMNode()`.

I checked in react documentation and they say something like

> Never access refs inside of any component's render method – or while any component's render method is even running anywhere in the call stack

I'm a very newbie in react and i think this is referring to my current situation.

But they also have another way of using refs by passing a callback in ref which will be used when some button is clicked as seen here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

I followed the example by

- Adding a ref callback like this `ref={(ref) => this.myTextInput = ref}`
  in my input tag.
- Instead of the button, i triggered the function when the list item is clicked. This doesn't work since the `this.myTextInput` isn't created yet. (Since this function is triggered when list item is clicked and it's before the input is rendered.
- At this point i was stuck completely because i can't pass this ref to check it in componentDidMount.

I'm convinced that I'm missing on some understanding here please with refs, child components and callback. Please help.

Comment: You can try triggering a function and componentDidUpdate, when the list item is clicked.

Comment: did you try prop named `autoFocus` ?